# Can't create table 'student.#sql-f40_3' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

> Table 1

```
create table personal(

id int not null auto_increment unique,
name char(20) not null,
age int not null,
city varchar(20) not null default 'Delhi'
);
insert into personal(name,age,city) values
('anubhav',22,'delhi'),
('rohit',24,'agra');
```

> Table 2

```
create table applications(
 app_id int(5) not null auto_increment unique,
 city varchar(10) not null default 'Delhi'
);
insert into applications(city) values
 ('kolkata'),
 ('mumbai'),
 ('mumbai'),
 ('delhi'),
 ('agra'),
 ('agra');
```

> Then i apply foreign key here with the help of Alter command-

```
alter table personal add foreign key(city) references applications(app_id)
```

but i am getting an error: ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'student.#sql-f40_3' (errno: 150)

Comment: Also, an FK can only reference the PK on another table

Comment: MySQL / InnoDB supports an extension to the standard: _NDB requires an explicit unique key (or primary key) on any column referenced as a foreign key. InnoDB does not, which is an extension of standard SQL._ ... See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-identifiers) specifies:

Conditions and Restrictions

> 1.Corresponding columns in the foreign key
> and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign
> of fixed precision types such as INTEGER and DECIMAL must be the same.
> The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary
> (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be
> the same.
>
> 2.MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
> referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
> columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
> index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
> exist. This index might be silently dropped later if you create
> another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
> index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

The data type must be the same.

You could do:

```
alter table personal add foreign key(city) references applications(city)
```

But, the columns on both tables should be indexed.
See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=358a4e4a5adea5ece2aa322c306942e4)

Answer (score 0):

you desing in not normalized

your personal table should only reference the id.

City name in the applications should be unique, so i added it in the create table, there is no need for two or more delhis in a table(see normalisation)

If you really want to use in personal the city name, you must like i already made refernece the coty name of appcations or define a KEY for that column.

Further the datatyoes of the columns must always be the saem in both table for the foreign key

```
create table personal(

id int not null auto_increment unique,
name char(20) not null,
age int not null,
city int not null default 0
);

create table applications(
 app_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
 city varchar(10) not null unique default 'Delhi'
);

alter table personal add foreign key(city) references applications(app_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have small bugs such as not putting **null** in the **insert** for the **autoincrement** and if it is **primary key** you should not put **not null**.

## Table personal

```
create table personal(

id int auto_increment primary key,
name char(20) not null,
age int not null,
city varchar(20) not null default 'Delhi'
);
insert into personal values (null,'anubhav',22,'delhi'),
                            (null,'rohit',24,'agra');
```

## Table applications

```
create table applications(
 app_id int(5) auto_increment primary key,
 city varchar(10) not null default 'Delhi'
);
insert into applications values(null,'kolkata'),
                               (null,'mumbai'),
                               (null,'mumbai'),
                               (null,'delhi'),
                               (null,'agra'),
                               (null,'agra');
```

## Alter table

```
alter table personal add foreign key(city) references applications(app_id)
```